# Find length of array sent from php to javascript

Tags: php, javascript, json

I have an array in PHP.

```
$numArray=array("1","2","3","4");
```

I want to transfer this array to javascript along with other data.
I do the following-

```
  $json = array(
          'num' => $numtArray
     );
```

In javascript I do the following.

```
var json=<?php echo json_encode($json); ?>;
console.log(json['num'].length);
```

I get undefined in console. How do I find length of this array?

Comment: Have you taken a look at the generated JavaScript code?

Comment: What does the actual HTML/JavaScript look like when the page is rendered?

Comment: Oh dear, I need some sleep. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

`numArray` v.s. `numtArray`. Notice the extra `t`... you're not assigning your array, you're assigning an undefined variable, producing a null.

Answer (score 0):

```
var jsonText = "<?php echo json_encode($json); ?>";
var jsonData = JSON.parse(jsonText);
console.log(jsonData['num'].length);
```

Answer (score 0):

To transfer to json u need to encode your data, like this:

```
$json = array(
    'num' => $numtArray
);
$json = json_encode($json);
```

In JavaScript you need to parse json string

```
var json=<?php echo $json; ?>;
console.log(JSON.parse(json));
```

what is that show you? It seems to be an object with key 'num', which is an array you looking for.

I hope that will help you.

Comment: In your JavaScript code, `var json` is *not* a string, so you don't need `JSON.parse`.  JSON can be evaluated as JavaScript code, so `var json` is already an object, no parsing needed.  If you did `var json="<?php echo $json; ?>";`, then you'd need to parse it.